# Cannot Read From Multimeter with RS232 Communication

Tags: serial-port

I am currently attempting to use a computer and RS232 connection to control a HP 34401A Multimeter. I am able to use commands such as "SYSTem:REMote" or "*TST" however when I attempt to use a command that sends back information nothing is returned to the computer. If I use another return command directly after I get a -410 error signifying that the output buffer is full. Are there any commands I need to use to tell it to send the information to the computer? I have been looking through the manual for one but cannot find it.

Extra Info:

1. RS232 Connection Setup: Baudrate=9600, Data bits=8, Stop bits=2, Parity=None
2. Since the connection is DTE to DTE I am using a null modem cable
3. I am using Termite to send commands to the multimeter

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Does the meter use RTS/CTS flow control lines? You may need to wire these to a "OK to send" level to get anything out of it. Not getting your command would be another reason it might not respond, is it definitely receiving the commands you send?

Comment: Yeah the meter does (or can) use hardware flow control, the manual says it won't send anything unless DSR is valid. See https://www.manualslib.com/manual/578999/Hp-34401a.html?page=151#manual One solution might be to enable hardware flow control in Termite, not sure if you can do that?

Comment: @barny The multi-meter is definitely getting the commands that im sending as it will run tests and set remote mode. I have been using the RTS/CTS flow control but the manual excerpt you sent says to use DTR/DSR so I will have to try that. Thanks!

Comment: @barny I used DTR/DSR with the multi-meter, it gave me the same problems as the the previous flow control. I would be able to use commands that tell the multi-meter to do something however any commands that would return something to the computer wouldn't return anything.

Comment: so you are definitely controlling it but not receiving anything back - could be anything along the return path - the output of the multimeter isn't working, the output of the multimeter is being inhibited by flow control, the cable/connectors have a bad wire on the return path or flow control to the meter, your serial port receiver is broken, ...

Comment: @barny Thanks for all the help! I finally figured out what the problem was. You were right there was a problem along the path, turns out I was using a loop-back handshake cable instead of the full-handshake cable. Thanks again!